# Unable to check if jQuery var is undefined

Tags: jquery

Here is my Code  that i tried:

```
var moduleLoaded = jQuery.data("#module", "loaded");

if(typeof moduleLoaded === undefined)
{
    moduleLoaded = true;
    jQuery.data("#module", "loaded", moduleLoaded);
    console.log(jQuery.data("#module", "loaded", moduleLoaded));
}
```

The if statement doesn't get hit. 
I also tried `if(!moduleLoaded)` and then I get the error `"Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"`. `if(moduleLoaded == '')` also won't work. This code gets hit twice so I need it to be true on the second loop.

Comment: Wrap `undefined` in quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator returns a string, you should compare the value with `'undefined'` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Indicates that JQuery is not loaded.

Also, `if(typeof moduleLoaded === undefined)` has a mistake: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string, so use `'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as below

```
var moduleLoaded = jQuery.data("#module", "loaded");
if(typeof moduleLoaded == `undefined`)
{
    moduleLoaded = true;
    jQuery.data("#module", "loaded", moduleLoaded);
    console.log(jQuery.data("#module", "loaded", moduleLoaded));
}
```

`==` operator will compare just values whereas `===` will compare values with type.